# How can I pull a new request from my index with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have an index that creates randomly generated dynamic content.

So everytime you load the index, it'll create a series of view that are dependent on what my Rails model has produced and sent to Backbone.

From backbone, I am curious what I could do to "refresh" the page without doing something like this :

```
window.location = '/'
```

I'd like to do it within Backbone.. something like this :

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/', {trigger: true, replace: true});
```

But this doesn't necessarily send a new request to the url.

All I would need to do to accomplish my goals is send a GET request to `/`, which should return a JSON object I can pipe through the rest of my Backbone app.

Is there a way to send this request within Backbone? Or should I just go a traditional jQuery route, and just make a `$.get` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your REST api returns a JSON object, simply use a `Backbone.Model` to structure this data. You can then bind events to do whatever you like in your application.

```
var RandomData = Backbone.Model.extend({ url: '/' });

var randomData = new RandomData();

// Here, `Backbone` can be substituted by any `View`, `Collection`, `Model...
Backbone.listenTo( randomData, 'change', function() {
  //Do something everytime this changes.
});

// When you need to issue a GET '/' request. The following will put the 
// JSON response inside of `randomData.attributes`
randomData.fetch();
```

Comment: `.fetch()` returns an object with things like `success`, `responseText`, etc. Where would the JSON object be?

Comment: The responseText is all the HTML of the page, where I just want the JSON object.